# How build a ternary relationship in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I have three entities:

- User
- Profile
- Status

Summarized, users has a profile foreach status.

**EXAMPLE**

Users table records

```
user
id   |   name
1        user1
2        user2
3        user3
```

Status table records (this records is previously seeded)

```
status
id (PK) |  title (string)
1          student
2          collaborator
3          teacher
```

Profile table structure

```
PROFILE  
user_status_id  (PK) (FK)  
institution (string)
year (timestamp)
```

*user1* is registered as *student* and fill your profile based on this status. After, he change your status to *collaborator* and fill another profile referred to this new status.

With that, i want to know:

- When *user1* was *student*?
- the *user1* was already *collaborator* ever?
- Which institution *user1* had frequented when he was *student*?

My first problem is:

**How to model this relationship?**

I'm not sure but think the above situation is a *ternary relatinoship* case, right?

And Second problem:

**How build using Laravel Eloquent Relationships?**

Comment: I can see your current table structure is not idle it may work for now but as your application or relation will grow you may have many challenges are you able to change db structure or is it out of your control?

Answer (score 1):

**Let's start with relationship**

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'user';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    public function status(){
        return $this->hasOne(Status::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasMany(Profile::class,'user_id','id');
    }
}

class Status extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'status';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }


}

class Profile extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'profile';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }

}
```

Above relation would somehow will get you what you need but just writing this relation made me question your table structure.

**Suggestion DB Change For Better Relation**

**User**
    id, username, email, ........

**Status**
    id, status, description, ........

**Institutions**
    id, name, address, ............

**User_Status_Institution**
    user_id,status_id,institution_id,timestamp,.......

This structure allows us that we can have Institution details even if there is no user_profile for that institution. Previous structure you had you can only have institution (name only) detail if and only if there is user profile. Also you can change institution (Name/address/phone etc) at one place and it will update it for all users.

As much as possible try that you can make information to be independent if possible because that reflects in models, object and relations.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: and if i want to know "Which institution user1 had frequented when he was student"?

Comment: i'm able to change db structure

Comment: Ok in that case tomorrow I'll suggest better db structure to support profile & status with example..